# Hudson SVN sync problem

Tags: svn, hudson

I am using Hudson 1.224, polling an SVN rep in another machine. When Hudson checks out (or updates) the build revision, it is never the latest one. Then the build happens on an old revision of the source code. The VERSIOND file has the wrong revision.

Also, Hudson won't stop building the task,  unless I tell it manually to. When a build is over, it loops and builds again.

I tried creating another hudson task, but apparently this is not the problem. The hudson host machine doesn't have disk space problems either.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I'd suggest this question might be more suited to serverfault, it seems more like a sysadmin question than a programming one.

Comment: Since it is a question about a 'tool that developers usually use', as described in the faq, I don't see any problem with this question being posted here. 

Agree with you, though. It would be more 'in place' there. Will consider this the next time, thanks for the tip.

Comment: 1.224 is over 2 years old ... you really should upgrade.  Otherwise you'll have many incompatibilities with plugins.

Comment: We're already upgrading our projects to another hudson farm, but some (rather old) ones are still on this old Hudson. Thanks for your concern, anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are the clocks in sync on the two servers?

Comment: Actually, they were not. The SVN server was a day ahead, I just corrected this and am waiting for the build to finish and check the version.